# How to use select to post data to the backend using Angular 9, Node JS, Express and MySQL

Tags: angular

I have a form in which a user can update the user information.  I would like to change the html format such that instead of the user being able to input a string they have to choose from a drop down menu selection of options.  I have the general idea for doing this but am stuck on the binding of the data.  In the original form, where the user would enter in the state they are from I have the following code.

```
          <mat-form-field>

                    <input matInput type="text" id="user_state" name="user_state" 
                     placeholder="SC" [(ngModel)]="user.user_state" required>

          </mat-form-field>
```

I understand that I am using the data binding with the ngModel directive, how would I convert this into an select options format and then send the data that the user selects to the backend?

Comment: What will the dropdown have ?
If you say dropdown menu selection of options, at first you need to have an array to show data there.
Then you handle the input or the selected value and that value you send to the backend.
I will add a dropdown with some data for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official Angular documentation for dropdowns you can find here.
As I said you need an Array to show data.

For example like this.

```
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor() {}
  
  countries: any = [
    {
      full: "Great Britain",
      short: "GB"
    },
    {
      full: "United States",
      short: "US"
    },
    {
      full: "Canada",
      short: "CA"
    }
  ];
  selectedCountry: string = "GB";
  
  selectedCountryControl = new FormControl(this.selectedCountry);

}
```

This is the HTML.

Angular Material - mat-select examples

```
<div style="padding: 20px;">
<h1>Model Forms</h1>

<div style="padding: 0 0 20px 20px">
<h3>Value string</h3>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select
    name="countryString"
    [(value)]="selectedCountry"
    placeholder="Country"
  >
    <mat-option [value]="'GB'">Great Britain</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="'US'">United States</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="'CA'">Canada</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

&nbsp;&nbsp; Selected = {{selectedCountry}}
</div>
</div>
```

For more you have this `stackblitz` here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-nhweaq

Comment: I think I understand, I will look at the example you gave me and do some more research.  I am basically just using an array of the fifty states within an update user form, I am very new to coding so some things click relatively easily and others not so much.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @ThomasKremer No problem let me know if it works for you.
If you cannot go further you can write to me and I will answer you.

Comment: is there a way to send you my code to the component.html and component.ts file so that you can see what it is I am doing and talking about without violating the forum rules?

Comment: Create a stackblitz and post your code there.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k7ym8z in this stackblitz paste your code.

Comment: Ok, I added the code from both pages to the app.component.ts and app.component.html  files on stackblitz, I also included my user model, everything is working as is and it is posting the updated data to the backend api and the database, I just need some help cleaning it up and understanding how to implement the select and options in a more concise manner.  As is I am pulling the data straight from the form itself and not using any loops or arrays for filtering. I appreciate your time and help, not many are willing.

Comment: @ThomasKremer I am not seeing your changes in stackblitz can you share the link I will take a look there.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k7ym8z?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @ThomasKremer Nope I dont see anythign please save your data and then give me the link.

Comment: Ok I will try to figure out how to do that after dinner. I am sorry, I thought it was saved.

Comment: Try this one. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vhjepj

Comment: @ThomasKremer I will simplify that for you and then will give the corrent answer.

Comment: @ThomasKremer I have changed the stackblitz only with dropdown.
Look here.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jnvkwt

Comment: now I see what you are talking about, this makes much more sense to me now.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem glad to help you.

Comment: Would you be willing to help me with understanding something new.  Stackexchange won't allow me to post it as a question because it is too basic I guess. @Abedin.Ahuniqi

Comment: @ThomasKremer No problem.
You can write me direct here or to contact me on linkedin.
https://www.linkedin.com/in/abedin-zhuniqi/

Comment: So I am working on a static web page where I am using an AJAX call to bring in a list of repositories.  Because there are so many repos, I would like to change the AJAX request to list the repos 8-10 at a time and maybe use a button on the html to navigate through them.  I put my code on stackblitz here --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/ajax-requests?file=index.js.  How is the best way to go about this and what would it look like? @Abedin.Zhuniqi

Comment: @ThomasKremer I will take a look about it and you will let u know.

Comment: @ThomasKremer I have looked there and I am not sure how I can help you.
But I am working for the moment at my job will it be ok if I answer tomorrow ?

Comment: Sure there is no rush. I appreciate you even looking much less answering. So thank you. @Abedin.Zhuniqi

Comment: I think I may have worked it out.  The solution is on the same link I gave you earlier, if you see any improvements let me know.  Thank you for your support and assistance, it is greatly appreciated more than you know. :) @Abedin.Zhuniqi

Comment: @ThomasKremer Sorry for not writing back from Friday.
I have checked your code and for my opinion it is very good enough for your case.

Comment: No worries about the delay @Abedin.Zhuniqi.  I really appreciate all your help, I know you are busy and have other things going on.

Comment: I think I need some help, I am encountering this error Object is possibly 'null'. within my angular projects now, using the same code that has worked for me for months and I don't know really how to get around it.  I asked a question in the main chat however nobody is really explaining or helping me with it. @Abedin.Zhuniqi ?

Comment: @ThomasKremer Sorry I was in vacation, I am back today.
I will write you tomorrow, sorry for the late answer.

Comment: No worries @Abedin.Zhuniqi, thanks I appreciate it.

Comment: @ThomasKremer can you create a stackblitz that I can see ?

Comment: Hey @Abedin.Zhuniqi, I have been doing volunteer work for my church, I should be finishing up tomorrow so I can create a stackblits tomorrow night.

Comment: I went ahead and put the front end for my project on stackblitz.  I am trying to work out 2 things. 1. paginator and 2 auto auth method.on refresh users are logged out and not supposed to be.  I will upload the backend for you to view as well @Abedin.Zhuniqi FRONTEND: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sean-blog?https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sean-blog. The backend is an Node JS express with MySQL, how do I make it viewable for you?

Comment: @ThomasKremer I really dont know where to write the backend.
I checked the code but didn't realize why it is `null`

Comment: I could link you to the repository that I have the entire project in, maybe you could examine both ends and see what you can see?  I know that something is wrong because the code I used to count documents is for mongodb and this project is using MySQL and sequelize and therefore it isn't documents but rows.  Aside from that I am lost. https://github.com/tkremer72/My_Angular_SEAN_Blog @Abedin.Zhuniqi